# How to override jest.mock defined in a setupFiles (jest.config.js)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In jest.config.js:

```
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.init.js'],
```

In jest.init.js :

```
jest.mock('xxx/layout', () => ({
  ...
  isMobile: false,
  ...
}))
```

So in all tests that import isMobile from 'xxx/layout' isMobile will be false

Now i tried to override isMobile in some tests like so:

```
jest.mock('xxx/layout', () => ({ isMobile: true }))

isMobile.mockImplementation(() => true)
```

But it's not working!

What would be the good way  to do it?

Answer (score 5):

You must reimport the module again after your second mock:
In your test file:

```
test('Test', () => {
  jest.mock('xxx/layout', () => ({ isMobile: true }))
  const layout = require('xxx/layout'); // require the new mock
  // run your test here
});
```

The setup file is run when Jest is setting up your testing environment. You can see the sequence of the job like below:

1. Jest runs `jest.init.js`, mocks `xxx/layout`;
2. Jest runs individual test file, and if you import your module before your override is run, it will not update dynamically